# Iterating over input in QGIS Model Designer to draw buffer

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to draw radii around different points. Because there's also some additional steps involved and it has to be done for several points, I'm trying to make a script in the Model Designer.

For the following steps, it's important that the created radii are separate vector objects. To achieve this regularly, I choose "iterate over this layer" in the buffer tool. But I cannot do this in the Designer, meaning all the radii are output in a single layer. Is this just impossible in the Model Designer? I've seen it working for other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Vector Features** input parameter and you will have the option to iterate over... when executing the model:

[image]